# Powershell module function not visible in Get-Modules

Tags: powershell

I have a simple powershell module containing a single function, an abridged version of this is as follows:

```
function My-Func
{
.
.
.
} 
Export-ModuleMember -Function 'My-Func'
```

My manifest file contain a line to explicitly export this:

FunctionsToExport = "My-Func"

Everything uploads to the powershell gallery via Publish-Module without any problems, then when I come to install this and run Get-Module, I do not see the function in the export commands column of the output, also I when I attempt to call the function powershell tells me it does not exist.

I have a psm1 file for my module and a psd1 manifest, for some reason when I only see Manifest as the module type, I'm guessing I need to see script ?.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you need to specify the functions in an array, even if there is only one: `FunctionsToExport = @('My-Func')`.  Get a clean example manifest file by using `New-ModuleManifest`

Comment: Is it correct that when I perform a Get-Module, the type of the module that comes up is manifest ?, or should this be script ?

Comment: I've created a new manifest file and specified the exported function in an array, unfortunately this has made no difference.

Comment: Fields like `FunctionsToExport` will work fine with scalars - it just autoconverts the scalar to an array. But it's a best practice to always use arrays as it makes updating the manifest later on easier. With respect to the function not showing up, if the module type is `Manifest` then it sounds like you haven't set the `RootModule` property to point at the `.psm1` file. If the manifest is correct, then the module type should be `Script`.

Comment: Bruce - setting the RootModule did the trick, if you can provide this as the answer, I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

in your .psm1: 
remove the Exported-ModuleMember line

in your .psd1: 
RootModule = 'yourmodule.psm1'
FunctionsToExport = @('function1','function2')

the psd1 file FunctionsToExport works like the Exported-ModuleMember command.  it's a cleaner way to define things from one centralized file.